# Not able to upload JSON in MongoDB using Java

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I am trying to upload JSON file in MongoDB using Documents, but getting the following error. I'm new to Mongo. Can I get any help?

**Exception in thread "main" org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: readStartDocument can only be called when CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT, not when CurrentBSONType is ARRAY.**

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import java.io.*;
import com.mongodb.client.model.BulkWriteOptions;
import com.mongodb.client.model.InsertOneModel;
import org.bson.Document;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        //System.out.println(new File("").getAbsolutePath());
        // Creating a Mongo client
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("mongotest");
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("jsondata");

        int count = 0;
        int batch =100;

        List<InsertOneModel<Document>> docs =  new ArrayList<>();
        //System.out.println(docs.getClass().getName());
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("mongotest.json"))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            //    System.out.println(Document.parse(line));
                docs.add(new InsertOneModel<>(Document.parse(line)));
                count++;

            if (count == batch) {
                collection.bulkWrite(docs, new BulkWriteOptions().ordered(false));
                docs.clear();
                count = 0;
            }
            }
        }
            catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("The file doesn't exist");
            }
            catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("The file could not be read");
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your code/what you have attempted to do.

Comment: @tomerpacific - I have uploaded the code. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you share the `mongotest.json` contents?
Each `line` must be an object (surrounded in `{}`), not an array (surrounded in `[]`).

**Edit:**
To fix your issue, instead of reading using `BufferedReader` do this:

```java
...
var json = Files.readString("mongotest.json", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
var jsonarray = new JSONArray(json);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
    var line = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
    docs.add(new InsertOneModel<>(Document.parse(line.toString())));
    count++;
}
...
```

Comment: This is how my content looks.
[
  {
    "Invoice ID": "750-67-8428",
    "Product line": "Health and beauty",
    "Unit price": 74.69,
    "Quantity": 7,
    "Tax 5%": 26.1415,
    "Total": 548.9715,
    "Date": "1/5/2019",
    "Time": "13:08",
    "Payment": "Ewallet"
  } 
] 
Every object is surrounded in { } but the entire file is surrounded in [ ]. Does that make difference?

Comment: It does make a difference. You want to send only `{ "Invoice ID": "750-67-8428", ... "Payment": "Ewallet" }` to the `Document.parse`, so you need to either skip `[` and `]`... or parse it and iterate over the objects (see **edit**).

Comment: I removed [ ] from my file. Now it gives me "JSON reader was expecting a name but found '<eof>' " error when I'm trying to add in the doc.

Comment: Instead of removing `[]` from your file (which gives you invalid JSON). Do what I suggested in **edit**.